# C - do these functions generate garbage?

Tags: c

I don't think they do, because delete uses the free() function, and replace just changes values, and doesn't make new nodes.  I'm asking because I'm coming from Java and I'm new to memory allocation.

```
IntNodePtr delete(int i, IntNodePtr p) {
  /* End of list check */
  if(p == NULL)
    return NULL;

  /* Check if current node is the one to delete */
  if(p->myInt == i) {
    IntNodePtr temp;
    temp = p->next;

    free(p);
    return temp;
  }

  p->next = delete(i, p->next);
  return p;
}

IntNodePtr replace(int i, int j, IntNodePtr p) {
  if(p == NULL)
    return NULL;

  if(p->myInt == i)
    p->myInt = j;

  p->next = replace(i, j, p->next);
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Considering how you used both methods, they look fine to me.

Comment: Although it's perfectly legal to call your function `delete` in C, I'd strongly recommend renaming it to something else (such as `delete_node`) so that it can be called from C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

In C, we don't call allocated memory that is no longer used "garbage", but a "memory leak".

You only need to `free` memory that you have previously allocated using `malloc`. In this case, none of your functions call `malloc`, and hence they don't need to `free` anything. (Though the `delete` function looks like it is `free`ing memory allocated somewhere else in the program. That is fine too.)

Comment: Keep in mind that C APIs are notoriously irregular on ownership issues too.  He may not directly allocate memory and still have to free it because an API he called returned some dynamically-allocated memory itself.

Comment: "hence they don't need to free anything" is tempting me to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

In `delete` you `free` the object because, once the pointer is replaced, there will be no way to access it. All good there.

In `replace` objects are only modified in place. Nothing is created or destroyed so `malloc` and `free` are not involved.

Note that these functions may cause a stack overflow error if the list is too long. Also, `replace` always returns its argument `p`, so there is no need for it to return anything. Leaving a tail call at the end of the function in place of `p->next = replace( …` would (all but) eliminate the stack overflow risk. Recoding `delete` as a loop would likewise perhaps be somewhat safer.

Comment: I agree with the removal of recursion. Never write recursive functions for recursion's own sake. In this particular program, it does two things: 1) slow the code down a lot, and 2) make it less readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(p->myInt == i) {
    IntNodePtr temp;
    temp = p->next;

    free(p);
    return temp;
  }
```

This code is questionable. What do you do with the returned pointer? To me, it seems as if you delete a node in the middle of the linked list without care for the previous "next pointer". After p is deleted, the previous next pointer will point at invalid memory. I.e. you cut off the list in the middle.

Answer (score -2):

In C" garbage" is generated when free is called, there is no "garbage collection" in C; unless it has been implemented -sorry if I am stating the obvious! So, delete will generate "garbage" - regarding replace your observation is correct.

Comment: How does `free` generate garbage? I'm tempted to downvote this for being totally unhelpful, if not inaccurate.

Comment: -1: I've stared at this answer for 2+ minutes and I still don't understand it.  Garbage (AKA a memory leak) is what is generated when `free` is **not** called.  I'm wondering if this "answerer" has a good grip on the English language.

Comment: I think what the answer is trying to say is that once you `free`, the contents of that memory are now indeterminate and off limits -- as opposed to right before the `free` call when you had good valid memory -- and now after the `free` call the pointer points to garbage? (Although that's OK because you're just asking for it if you use pointers after your `free` them)

Comment: @user470379 - thanks @Chris,@JimR - yes I should have been careful while framing the answer